# FTP Server error, A receive socket error occurred

Tags: ftp, socket

I have a FTP server, Core FTP server, where i get errors for inbound transfers to one of the accounts. The inbound files are only 1k in size.

The error occures in 5% of all inbound transfers.
Error message in server log:
STOR failed, error 21 (A receive socket error occurred.)

It is a windows server 2008 R2. It started to happen just after windows update 21/april-2015 had , should not have been done automatically, installed a bunch of updates (had not been done since november 2014).

I have googled the net for possible solutions but i cant find anything that could explain this behaviour. I only get the errors on one account so it feels like it could be a client issue...but since it started to happen just after 75 server fixes were installed i have a hard time only going in that direction.

Anyone here with any tips or hints on this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use a different FTP client with that account? What client do you use? How does the error exhibit on the client side?

Comment: I have no power over the client that account is using. They are using some kind of self made program written in Java. When i asked for error message they give me this: "exceptionConnection reset". Not much and they can not give me more.